# How do you get Sails to allow long polling req's taking over 2 mins?

Tags: jquery, sails.js

The frontend is doing a long polling Ajax call to a route. The controller lets an async child process handle the processing. This will take over 2 min.

However the controller gets called a second time at the 2 min mark. I suspect Sails might have a 2 min timeout on req handling. This is reasonable in general but not in this particular case.

I checked Chrome is sending just 1 XHR, which does not get a reply before the controller is called a second time.

Express middleware is also being called when the controller is called a second time.

The controller is basically the following. The cb in asyncChildProcess is called when the child sends a reply.

```
module.exports = {
  run: function (req, res) {
    asyncChildProcess.exec('the command', 'data to', function (errObj, command, dataFrom) {
      if (errObj) {
        res.json(errObj);
      } else {
        res.send('ran successfully');
      }
    }
  }
};
```

The controller gets called from a req, the child starts processing, 2 smins elapse during neither the cb is called nor another req is received, at the 2 min mark the controller gets called a second time.

How can I control the timeout and/or how else can I handle long running req's?